# Android:Null Pointer Exception while trying to set text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to set text view which is in layout which is not set in Content View. I am getting NullPointerException while tring to set TextView.

```
 TextView titleView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
          titleView.setText("test" );
```

While the xml in which this TextView is there is as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_gravity="center">



       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp" 
            android:background="@drawable/background"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

I am using the above file title_layout in action bar with the following code :-

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.title_layout);
```

What could be the error and possible solution to it.

Comment: Where do you inflate this layout? Post that part of the code.

Comment: What's the error showing in logcat??

Comment: Please Post The code May be Check Setcontentview Methed

Comment: @Apoorv I have posted the code where I am using this layout file

Comment: @LearningBasics-Android see My Answer .. hope it ll use for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextView titleView;
```

**In onCreate Method**

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#0065B2")));  // backgroung color 
    actionBar.setIcon("set icon here");

    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
    //
    titleView = ((TextView) actionBar.getCustomView()
            .findViewById(R.id.titleOfActionBar))

    titleView.setText("test" );
```

Comment: @LearningBasics-Android then please give upVote :D

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you find view in the wrong place. Try to get view from action bar, like:

```
TextView search = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.mytext);
```

Comment: thanks !! it exactly was the error !! A lot of downvoting on the question I dont know why?

Answer (score 1):

```
 TextView titleView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
          titleView.setText("test" );
```

This has to come after `setContentView()` has been called in `onCreate()`. That is one reason for an `NPE`.

**Update:**

Use this:

```
getActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.mytext);
```

After you have set the custom view for your `ActionBar` and also use the method to enable showing of custom view for your action bar `getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)`. You will end up with NPE again if you dont do this.

Also, get the `TextView` after you have set the view for action bar.

Comment: this has been done after setContentView() that's why I have mentioned that this particular xml is not  set in content view